# replicate by columns, but transposing in r with vectorization

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a matrix like this:

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

and I would like to have every column repeated "m" times, but transposing into files and concat the results horizontally. I mean, suppose "m" is 3, I would like to have something like this:

```
matrix(c(1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9,1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9,1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9), 
                     nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Is there any vectorized way to do this?

I have tried using rep to replicate the columns and then transposing, but I end with many rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rep`

```
matrix(rep(m1, each=nrow(m1)), nrow=3)
```

Or

```
`dim<-`(rep(m1, each=nrow(m1)), dim(m1)*c(1,3))
```

Or

```
t(replicate(nrow(m1), c(m1)))
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```